# Get the creation date of a table's column

Tags: sql-server

I found a script to get the column information:

```
SELECT 
   crdate as thisFieldIsNotTheCreationOfTheField1 ,
   refdate as thisFieldIsNotTheCreationOfTheField2 ,
   o.name AS [TableName],
   o.type,
   c.name AS [ColName],
   s.name AS [ColType],
   c.prec,
   c.scale,
   c.isnullable
FROM       
   dbo.sysobjects AS o
INNER JOIN
   dbo.syscolumns AS c ON c.id = o.id
INNER JOIN
   dbo.systypes AS s ON c.xtype = s.xtype
WHERE  
   o.type = 'U' and o.name='TableNa'
ORDER BY
   crdate
```

The column creation datetime isn't found.

How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the date/time a table's column was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425487/find-the-date-time-a-tables-column-was-created)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want :

```
SELECT obj.create_date 
from sys.objects obj 
inner join sys.columns col on obj.object_Id=col.object_Id 
WHERE col.name = @columnName
and obj.Name=@tableName
```

Comment: +1 for using the **new** catalog views in the `sys.` schema - folks: **ditch** the old `sysobjects` and the like! It's about time!

Comment: This obj.create_date is not correct , why ?
Do a simple test :

'Create table test
(
A int null,
B int null,
C int null
);'

On sql server GUI , modify your table :
Insert a column X between A and B column.

execute 

'SELECT *
from sys.objects obj 
inner join sys.columns col on obj.object_Id=col.object_Id 
WHERE obj.Name='test'
ORDER BY obj.create_date' 

Normally X column must be the last , and he is in the seconde position.

Comment: It gives the date the table was created, not the column.